# No vuelven a estar ocultos los botones

Tags: javascript, html, css

ante todo muchas gracias de antemano.

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que tengo 2 botones, cuando pulso uno de ellos me despliega un formulario y cuando le doy al otro despliega el otro formulario hasta ahí bien.

El problema es que cuando pulso al otro botón automáticamente se esconda el contenido del otro botón y muestre el que he pulsado

Tengo creados 2 divs donde están los formularios que quiero abrir según el botón que le de

Este es mi código html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function mostraroculto1() {
        if (document.getElementById('basico').onclick) {
         document.getElementById('oculto1').style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('oculto1').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    function mostraroculto2() {
        if (document.getElementById('detallado').onclick) {
        document.getElementById('oculto2').style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById('oculto2').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input class="basico" type="button" name="basico" id="basico" value="BASICO" onclick="mostraroculto1() "/>
<input class="detallado" type="button" name="detallado" id="detallado" value="DETALLADO" onclick="mostraroculto2()"/>



<br>
<br>

  <div id="oculto1" style="display: none;">

    <form action="informebasico.php" method="post" >
        <h2>INFORME BASICO</h2>
        <br>Desde:<input type="date" name="fecha1basico" ><br>
        <br>Hasta:<input type="date" name="fecha2basico"><br>
        <br><input type="submit" value="INFORME PDF">

    </form>

  </div>

  <div id="oculto2" style="display: none;">


        <form action="informedetallado.php" method="post" >
        <h2>INFORME DETALLADO</h2>
        Trabajador <input type="text" name="trabajador"><br>

        <br>Desde:<input type="date" name="fecha1detallado"><input type="time" name="hora1detallado"><br>
        <br>Hasta:<input type="date" name="fecha2detallado"><input type="time" name="hora2detallado"><br>
        <br><input type="submit" value="INFORME PDF">

        </form>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hice esta modificación, en lugar de poner la condicion `else`, al momento que hagas click en un boton, se esconda el otro div y viceversa.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function mostraroculto1() {
        if (document.getElementById('basico').onclick) {
         document.getElementById('oculto1').style.display = 'block';
         document.getElementById('oculto2').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    function mostraroculto2() {
        if (document.getElementById('detallado').onclick) {
        document.getElementById('oculto2').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('oculto1').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input class="basico" type="button" name="basico" id="basico" value="BASICO" onclick="mostraroculto1() "/>
<input class="detallado" type="button" name="detallado" id="detallado" value="DETALLADO" onclick="mostraroculto2()"/>



<br>
<br>

  <div id="oculto1" style="display: none;">

    <form action="informebasico.php" method="post" >
        <h2>INFORME BASICO</h2>
        <br>Desde:<input type="date" name="fecha1basico" ><br>
        <br>Hasta:<input type="date" name="fecha2basico"><br>
        <br><input type="submit" value="INFORME PDF">

    </form>

  </div>

  <div id="oculto2" style="display: none;">


        <form action="informedetallado.php" method="post" >
        <h2>INFORME DETALLADO</h2>
        Trabajador <input type="text" name="trabajador"><br>

        <br>Desde:<input type="date" name="fecha1detallado"><input type="time" name="hora1detallado"><br>
        <br>Hasta:<input type="date" name="fecha2detallado"><input type="time" name="hora2detallado"><br>
        <br><input type="submit" value="INFORME PDF">

        </form>

  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esto es lo que estaba intentando y creo que entre en un bucle y algo tan sencillo no lo conseguí realizar. Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda y tomo nota

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar de esta forma:

- Creas una clase `.hide` que lo que hace es que modifica el `display`
  a `display: none` y se lo agregas a cada `form`
- Creas una función que remueva la clase `.hide` de uno y se lo añada
  al otro. Si utilizas parámetros en la función. No te hace falta
  escribir 2 funciones que hagan lo mismo.

```js
const formBasico = document.getElementById('oculto1'),
      formDetallado = document.getElementById('oculto2'),
      btnBasico = document.getElementById('basico'),
      btnDetallado = document.getElementById('detallado');

btnBasico.onclick = function() {mostrarYOcultar(formBasico, formDetallado)}

btnDetallado.onclick = function() {mostrarYOcultar(formDetallado, formBasico)}


function mostrarYOcultar(elementoAMostrar, elementoAOcultar) { 
    elementoAOcultar.classList.add('hide');
    elementoAMostrar.classList.remove('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input class="basico" type="button" name="basico" id="basico" value="BASICO"/>
<input class="detallado" type="button" name="detallado" id="detallado" value="DETALLADO"/>

  <div id="oculto1" class="hide">

    <form action="informebasico.php" method="post" >
        <h2>INFORME BASICO</h2>
        <br>Desde:<input type="date" name="fecha1basico" ><br>
        <br>Hasta:<input type="date" name="fecha2basico"><br>
        <br><input type="submit" value="INFORME PDF">

    </form>

  </div>

  <div id="oculto2" class="hide">


        <form action="informedetallado.php" method="post" >
        <h2>INFORME DETALLADO</h2>
        Trabajador <input type="text" name="trabajador"><br>

        <br>Desde:<input type="date" name="fecha1detallado"><input type="time" name="hora1detallado"><br>
        <br>Hasta:<input type="date" name="fecha2detallado"><input type="time" name="hora2detallado"><br>
        <br><input type="submit" value="INFORME PDF">

        </form>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta Gabriel! tu respuesta es funcional y me ha servido de gran ayuda y para tener otra forma de hacerlo!

Answer (score 0):

usas bootstrap? prueba agregando/quitando la clase `d-none`

usas jQuery? prueba el método `$.addClass` y `.removeClass` con la clase antes mencionada

Comment: El op muestra usar JS puro

Comment: @Aprendiz y por eso no puedo preguntar o sugerir usos?

Comment: No uso bootstrap